# How to parse an XML file using AWS Glue service?

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have been asked to parse an XML file and dump it in our Database/Warehouse (still exploring the options). Below in the steps that I have done

1. Added the XML in an S3 bucket
2. Choose the file as a source in the Glue service
3. Choose an appropriate IAM user
4. Ran the crawler manually.

The crawler runs successfully but I cannot see any table structure or data being generated by Glue.

Looking forward to some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if there is any self closing tag in xml data.If yes then remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to user3774905's comments, also see if there are any opening / closing tags enclosing the xml data.  I had one JSON file used for processing, and the crawler ran successfully but tables are not created as the same case you had mentioned.  Upon checking the json data file, I found that JSON file have opening/closing tags "[, ]", alongwith the json file name as well as part of the json file.  After removing these extra lines and rerun the crawler, the table schema was created.

So, could be that your xml data file has some invalid entries.

Answer (score 0):

It think It's better to convert it to another format (e.g. parquet) using spark-xml, crawler could not work as expected due to issues with the xml format of the files.

You need to upload the jar to s3 and send the path to the job:
Dependent jars path:
s3://bucket/jars/spark-xml_2.11-0.4.1.jar

https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml